# How to create an asynchronous streaming websocket with Autobahn?

Tags: python, twisted, autobahn

I have been trying to put together this specific use case using Autobahn/Tiwsted with Python 2.7:

A websocket server listens to potential clients to connect. Those clients send a subscribe message along with their ID, and the websockets then serves those clients **specific content depending on their IDs**.

For the example, I just return their ID to the respective clients upon connection and I maintain a list of clients connected in the factory.

The strangest thing happens though, in the onMessage() method of the websocket server. The method is blocking, and therefore, makes the websocket crashing when 1000 clients send keep alive messages and the server needs to answer to all of them.

Example:

```
class MyServerProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):

    def onConnect(self, request):
        print("Client connecting: {0}".format(request.peer))

    def onOpen(self):
        print("WebSocket connection open.")

    def onMessage(self, payload, isBinary):
        time.sleep(20)
        if "ID" in msg_json:
            self.sendMessage("Your ID is : %s" % msg_json['ID'])

    def onClose(self, wasClean, code, reason):
        print("WebSocket connection closed: {0}".format(reason))
        self.factory.unregister(self)
```

With this code, if multiple clients try to connect, the server waits until the sleep is over for the first client to answer to the second, etc...

How can I make this method asynchronous?

I could of course use a Queue and several consumer threads but that wouldn't be the twisted/autobahn way of doing things, I believe.

Thank you very much

Comment: You simply don't sleep for 20 seconds, you have to schedule a call in 20 seconds. How to do that depends on the asynchronous framework you are using: Twisted or asyncio. On Twisted it will be `reactor.callLater(20, ...)`

Comment: I am using Twisted. The sleep is there in order to mimic load on the server, for example a lot of clients sending messages and the server needs to answer. Should I also use reactor.callLater() ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your "load simulation"?

Comment: @justinlevol remove the `time.sleep` and your code should run fine. Your main app is not where you want to simulate load. Use [`locust.io`](http://locust.io) for that or write a separate script to simulate load.